# Python - reindex monthly values

Tags: python, csv, indexing, nan

I have some Dataframes, of monthly averages as follow:

```
Month,Value1,Value2
02,1,1
03,2,2
04,3,3
06,4,4
07,5,5
08,6,6
09,7,7
10,8,8
12,9,9
```

My problem is that those Dataframes are missing some months, in the enclosed examples month 1, 5 and 11 are missing.

Therefore I would like to re-index the dataframe and fill the missing Values by NaN as follow:

```
Month,Value1,Value2
01,NaN,NaN
02,1,1
03,2,2
04,3,3
05,NaN,NaN
06,4,4
07,5,5
08,6,6
09,7,7
10,8,8
11,NaN,NaN
12,9,9
```

I did this small code:

```
data = pd.read_csv("test.csv", index_col=[0])
new_index = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']
data = data.reindex(new_index)
```

Unfortunately, the output is far from the desired one and all the values are now replaced by NaNs:

```
Month,Value1,Value2
01,NaN,NaN
02,NaN,NaN
03,NaN,NaN
04,NaN,NaN
05,NaN,NaN
06,NaN,NaN
07,NaN,NaN
08,NaN,NaN
09,NaN,NaN
10,NaN,NaN
11,NaN,NaN
12,NaN,NaN
```

Does anyone know why? and maybe how to fix that?

Comment: Are the month numbers really strings?

Comment: Try with `new_index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]` instead of `new_index = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read the csv, the index is of type `int64`, you can check with following:

```
data = pd.read_csv("test3.csv", index_col=[0])
print(data.index.dtype)
```

Result:

```
int64
```

Now, when using `reindex` as below:

```
new_index = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']
data = data.reindex(new_index)
```

In above, if `new_index` is all of type `str`, it does not match to the existing index and new object will be produced:
According to [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

> Docstring:
>
> > Conform DataFrame to new index with optional filling logic, placing
> >     NA/NaN in locations having no value in the previous index. A new object
> >     is produced unless the new index is equivalent to the current one and
> >     copy=False

Hence, you may want to try using new index with type of `int` instead of `str`:

```
new_index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]   
data = data.reindex(new_index)
```